# Checks for update when launch Java web start

Tags: java, jnlp, java-web-start

Application launch through Java web start(JWS) checks for update when we are launching it.
Is there any way that we can prompt the users to download updates and if user say yes then it'll download the update otherwise execute old application without update?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`update`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/syntax.html#update) element with a `policy` attribute of "prompt-update". For example:

```
<update check="always" policy="prompt-update">
```

Comment: Does this actually work for anyone? It certainly does not for me. It always updates with a new version.

Comment: @SamBarnum: Yes; try clearing cache; you might see if [JaNeLA](http://pscode.org/janela/) spots anything untoward.